# tf.keras: Handling iteration over variable-length sequences in custom Model without custom training method

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras, tensorflow2.x

I'm trying to implement a simple recurrent neural network architecture with attention for a sequence to sequence task using `tf.keras` in Tensorflow 2.1.
I've followed the [Tensorflow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/nmt_with_attention) on this mostly and so far, it is working.

However, the guide uses a self-written training function where I would like to use the various `tf.keras.Model` functions like `fit`, so I tried to adjust the code to allow me to use those.
The problematic point is the following:
In the decoder part, due to the attention architecture, one has to manually iterate over timesteps, do the attention computation and feed the result to the next step.
My decoder model looks something like this:

```py
class MyDecoderModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        ...

    def call(self, x):
        seq_in, state_in = x
        batch_size, seq_len = seq_in.shape
        for step in range(seq_len):
            do_stuff()
```

Most importantly, the sequence length of the input must be defined and not be `None`. But I want to work with variable sequence lengths.
As far as I understand, this makes the use of the Keras functional API, that I would normally use, impossible with this Model, since writing something like

```py
x = tf.keras.Input(shape=(None,))
x = MyDecoderModel()(x)
```

would feed the `None` into the call.
So I decided to work only with Model subclassing, writing a main model like

```py
class MyMainModel(tf.keras.Model):
    ...
    def call(self, x):
        enc_in, dec_in = x
        state = self.my_encoder(enc_in)
        dec_out = self.my_decoder((dec_in, state))
        return dec_out
```

This seems to work in principle, calling this main model with input data succesfully produces results.
However, when using the `fit()` method on this model, things happen that I don't understand:
First, the model is called with unknown batch size, but specified sequence length.
Subsequently, it is only called with specified batch size, but unknown sequence length.
Hence `None` is passed and the iteration fails.

Now why does this happen? During training, the sequence length of the batch should definitely be known, why is it not passed to my model?
Is there any chance of solving this without a custom training method?
I'd be very happy if someone could explain what's going on there...

Answer (score 1):

First thing: If your input data is a sequence, the shape fed to `Input` must have two values: (`timesteps, features)`. `timesteps` can be `None`, but `features` must have a fixed shape. If you only have one feature, do this:

```
x = tf.keras.Input(shape=(None, 1))
```

Second, you can use use variable timesteps in models with a few changes; `tf.unstack` is your friend here:

```
class MyDecoderModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        ...

    def call(self, x):
        seq_in, state_in = x
        step_number = 0
        steps_in = tf.unstack(seq_in, axis=SEQUENCE_AXIS)
        steps_out = []
        for step in batches_in:
            steps_out.append(do_stuff())
            step_number += 1
        return tf.stack(steps_out, axis=SEQUENCE_AXIS)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However using `tf.unstack()` fails with `ValueError: Cannot infer num from shape (150, None, 64)`, where 1 is my sequence axis.

Comment: Are you using `model.summary()` when you get this error?

Comment: No, I'm calling `model.fit()`

Comment: Could you post the error? And do you get the error in `model.fit()` or `model.compile()`?

Comment: Well, the error is that `ValueError` I pasted above. Im calling tf.unstack() on the output of an embedding layer with embedding dimension 64 and the batchsize is 150. The sequence length should be there in the middle.
I am getting this error in `model.fit()`, after `compile` has passed successfully. Note that for some reason, it is first called with in_seq shape `(None, seq_len)` and then again with `(batch_size, None)`.
Also note that as written above, calling the model directly with data is no problem.